# Get images by selected color on Product View page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, product-images, product-view-page

I want to get the **Images Array** from the **specific color** that the client **Selects** in the PRODUCT VIEW PAGE.

So i found something on

> templates/product/view/gallery.phtml

I found `$block->getGalleryImages()` But I couldn't do what i wanted, Because i only get the images from the **configurable product** (just the images from one color..) maybe i'm using in the wrong way, or i'm on the wrong file.

Any help is appreciated...